# Writing reference declaration and assignment in same statement

Tags: c++, g++

Is there anything wrong with writing a reference declaration and assignment in one statement. I have tried it using gcc and it seems to work.

```
int x = 10;
cout << "x = " << x << "\n";

int &y = x = 11;
cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
cout << "y = " << y << "\n";
```

gives me the expected output

```
x = 10
x = 11
y = 11
```

Is this expected to work on most compilers or will there be a portability issue?

Comment: better you avoid it if possible even though it works fine in most of the modern systems. but why take unnecessary risk when you have other secure paths

Comment: @Rohit - yes I decided to avoid it but wanted to check whether it should work and if there might be any other issues anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, there is an assignment operator, which can be used (at least in
principle) in any expression.  Note that in:

```
int& y = x = 11;
```

The first `=` is *not* an operator; it is part of the syntax of the data
definition.  What follows this `=` is an expression, which must result 
in an lvalue of type `int`.  Since `x` is an `int`, `x = 11` has type
`int`.  And the result of the built-in assignment operator is an lvalue,
referring to the object which was the target of the assignment, so
you've met the necessary conditions.

Of course, that doesn't mean that it's good code.